# If my view controller calls deinit(), does that mean that I don't have memory leaks?

Tags: ios, swift

If the view controller is able to call deinit(), does that mean I don't have strong reference cycles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your view controller's `deinit` block runs, it means your view controller isn't involved in a strong retain cycle. It doesn't mean your program is completely free of memory leaks.

If you want to be sure you don't have memory leaks, try using the Leaks instrument in Instruments.

[Finding Memory Leaks in Your App](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/Instruments_help_articles/FindingMemoryLeaksinYourApp/FindingMemoryLeaksinYourApp.html)